# WP Query with multiple tags by get the tags

Tags: wp-query, tags

I need to do a wp query that will get any post that has one tag or more.
My current code works for one tag, but I've try for multiple with the codex and I can't do it. Can you help me?

```
<?php
global $post;
foreach(get_the_tags($post->ID) as $tag) {
}

$recent_posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'cat'  => 20,
    'tag_slug__in' => $tag->name . ', ',
    'showposts' => 2
));
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you read [the Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters), you must pass an *array* as `tag_slug__in`. In this case though, I would use `tag__in` with IDs rather than slugs:

```
$tag_ids = array();
foreach( get_the_tags($post->ID) as $tag ) {
    $tag_ids[] = $tag->term_id;
}
$recent_posts = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'cat' => 20
    )
);
```